# when program reads characters from file it also reads some trash

Tags: c, file, char

This program reads from file RDLRDLLLL into buffer then transfers to a `char` array and ultimately transforms each character into an pseudo-code. The problem is: it also reads some odd characters, so my question is: where is the problem?

```
#define n 100

void main() {
  int i;
  char tablou_init[n];

  FILE *fp;
  long lSize;
  char *buffer;

  fp = fopen("date.in", "r");
  if (!fp) perror("date.in"), exit(1);

  fseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_END);
  lSize = ftell(fp);
  rewind(fp);

  /* allocate memory for entire content */
  buffer = calloc(1, lSize + 1);
  if (!buffer) fclose(fp), fputs("memory alloc fails", stderr), exit(1);

  /* copy the file into the buffer */
  if (1 != fread(buffer, lSize, 1, fp)) fclose(fp), free(buffer), fputs(
      "entire read fails", stderr), exit(1);

  strcpy(tablou_init, buffer);

  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    if (tablou_init[i] == 'R') printf("<program>\n");
    else if (tablou_init[i] == 'D') printf("<secventa de instructiuni>\n");
    else if (tablou_init[i] == 'L') printf("<consecutivitate de  descrieri>\n");
    else if (tablou_init[i] == 'T') printf("<tip>\n");
    else if (tablou_init[i] == 'I') printf("<lista de identificatori>\n");
    else if (tablou_init[i] == 'S') printf("<consecutivitate de instructiuni>\n");
    else if (tablou_init[i] == 'A') printf("<instructiunea de Atribuire>\n");
    else if (tablou_init[i] == 'F') printf("<instructiunea IF>\n");
    else if (tablou_init[i] == 'H') printf("<instructiune>\n");
    else if (tablou_init[i] == 'W') printf("<instructiunea WHILE>\n");
    else if (tablou_init[i] == 'i') printf("<identificator>\n");
    else if (tablou_init[i] == 'e') printf("<expresie>\n");
  }

  fclose(fp);
  free(buffer);
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    printf("%c", tablou_init[i]);
  }

}
```

[program run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BIFSW.jpg)

Comment: garbage in, garbage in,  Please indent your code properly!

Comment: Wow. Those lines with all the commas - sure it works, but it's so far away from "normal" a lot of people are going to call you on it!

Comment: This will land you an F: `fclose(fp),fputs("memory alloc fails",stderr),exit(1);`

Comment: yeah i know,i could use another array,but!it sure is easier to see what i want to do,and also it's a protype to see how the program works

Comment: How do you know you read "junk" - looks to me like you never take any notice of how much you have read and just assume you have read 100 bytes.

Comment: Do you know about the `switch` statement?

Comment: fclose(fp),fputs("memory alloc fails",stderr),exit(1);--about "this" it's certainly isnt mine it comes from this site also,im just trying to find the optimal solution

Comment: as i told you it's a "prototype" it sure isnt good

Comment: `strcpy(tablou_init, buffer);` -> probable buffer overflow.

Comment: It is more useful to post the output observed rather than describe it: "it also reads some odd characters".

Comment: Take note of John3136's comment, it seems like the most likely proximate cause.  As others have suggested, this is very unusual code and by munging together so many operations into single lines, you are going to make your life harder in the long term.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is quite simple:

You read the file contents into `buffer`, then copy it to `tablou_init`.  It is risky to not check for potential overflow, but let's assume the file really only contains a few bytes: these bytes and a trailing `'\0'` get copied by `strcpy`, but the rest of `tablou_init` is not initialized.

Therefore, looping over the whole `tablou_init` from `0` to `n` may produce random output as bytes beyond the `'\0'` are indeterminate and may be valid but unexpected instructions.

The fix is easy, change both `for` loops to this:

```
for (i = 0; i < lSize; i++)
```

Technically, the `tablou_init` array is not needed, looping over the contents of `buffer` is simpler and safer.

Reading lines from the input file with `fgets()` would be more reliable than your current method: you cannot reliably compute the file size with `ftell()`.  C11 7.21.9.4 says: *For a text stream, its file position indicator contains unspecified information, usable by the fseek function for returning the file position indicator for the stream to its position at the time of the ftell call;*.  You **do** open the stream in text mode.  This is probably not the explanation for your problem, but this method is not portable.

Comment: well it's a silly question but where exactly it should be placed?

Comment: Both loops should be changed

Comment: thank you,saved me a lot of time,i kinda like to accept criticism,as i am an amateur it sure helps me understand some mistakes i do))

Comment: i have a question,if i introduce a second line to file the file read fails,should i add something more?

Comment: Sorry about the blunt remarks, I understand this style is not yours, just be aware that it is inelegant and error prone. Please accept the answer and enjoy the journey.

Comment: Your code should work for multiple lines.  Maybe not exactly as expected.  If so, instead of reading the whole file at once, you could read one line at a time with `fgets()`.

Comment: it's not that the answer is wrong,it's a question that has nothing with this answer,it's just that this is another error which is not cause by your guiding,it persisted and still persists,sorry

Comment: really? would you please edit your question and post the actual output from the modified program with the specified input?

Comment: The reason you still get garbage output in your *program output* is you did not replace the second `for` loop after the `free(buffer);` statement.  You still print 100 characters, most of which are indeterminate because the `tablou_init` array is not full initialized, only the first 10 bytes are overwritten by `strcpy`. You can simply replace the loop with `printf("%s\n", tablou_init);`.